# simulate setInterval cycles in angular component tests

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have a component that starts a `setInterval` in its ngOnInit, with a period of 2 seconds.
Inside the setInterval, a have a function for which I have created a spy, and I want to test that within 7 seconds, the spy has been called 3 times. I want to tick the setInterval with a virtual clock, but my attempt failed (the setInterval continues to work a real clock). So I tried to tick setTimeout, but also without success:

```
     it('should call spy', fakeAsync(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
      }, 7000);

      tick(7000);
     }));
```

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The creation of the setInterval is simple:

```
export class MYComponent implements OnInit {
   interval;       

   constructor(private service: MyService) {}

   ngOnInit() {
       this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            service.method();
       }, 2000)   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first(bad because this test will take 7 seconds of running) way:

```
it('should call spy', (done) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
        done();
      }, 7000);
     });
```

done callback can be used to defer the test complete time.
The second way is to fix clock

```
//somewhere where your component is ngOnInited, let say beforeEach
// async from @angular/core/testing
beforeEach(async(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComp);
  fixture.detectChanges();
}))
```

this should fix timers and your test would look somehow like

```
it('should call spy', fakeAsync(() => {
      tick(7000);
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);      
}));
```

Comment: was it called 1 times instead of 3 or 0? if 0 then could you provide a piece of code where set interval iscreated?

Comment: No I'm getting: `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: could you provide a piece of code where setInterval is created

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that angular never reaches a stable status. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this from within your tests. The correct way to test a setTimeout/setInterval is by using `fakeAsync` like @Andrei proposed:

```
it('should call spy', fakeAsync(() => {
  tick(7000);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);      
}));
```

But, because it's a `setInterval`, it never reaches stable. You can update your component to escape the NgZone from your `setInterval`:

```
export class MYComponent implements OnInit {
 interval;       

 constructor(private service: MyService, private nz: NgZone) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.nz.runOutsideAngular(() => {
       this.interval = setInterval(() => {
         this.nz.run(() => {
           service.method();
         });
       },  
   }
}
```